# Buck converter State-Plane Analysis

Tags: buck, control

Do you know how to use state-plane analysis to learn the zero-voltage-switching buck converter?

I searched for some papers, but most papers talk about LLC converter. I want to learn the ZVS of the buck converter.

1. Can somebody suggest to me some useful papers or material that I can learn from?
2. How can I find the state-plane analysis to learn?